# saving email in msg file on my filesystem

Tags: powershell, outlook

I need your help by saving email in msg file on my filesystem.

I have this powershell script to access the email

```
Add-Type -Assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook"
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application
$EmailsInFolder = $Outlook.Session.Folders.Item(1).Folders.Item(“Inbox”).Items
foreach ($EmailInFolder in $EmailsInFolder)
{ 
   //save email as *.msg
}
```

It works and I can read the email properties and print it on the console. But how I can save each mail I a separated msg file.

Thanks for your help

Stefan

Comment: Something like `$EmailInFolder.SaveAs PathToSave & FileName & '.msg', olMsg`

Comment: Also, don't hard code the folder indices and folder names. IN your particular case, you can use $Outlook.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)